# Is there any tabular tool in editor?

Tags: discussion, edits

Is there any table tool or markup which can facilitate user presenting tabular data? As such user need not to combine "-", "+", and "|" to create a visual  table like in this [post.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/504/foreign-key-violation-not-sure-why)

Comment: Um ... that's just the output from `describe` and `select`, printed using the 'code sample' feature  (the button w/ '101 010', or just indent everything a few spaces).

Comment: 4 spaces to be exact.

Answer (score 6):

As they're using [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) for formatting, it wouldn't then be able to present it.  There are some variants, like [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table), but they're not using it.

They *will* accept some HTML, but it's [a limited list, and table tags aren't included](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to ASCII art is to upload an image.  Simply create the table yourself (spreadsheets work well for this) and then upload a screenshot of the table.

[image: # Sample Table Image #]